# How to select rows above a certain value grouping by a different column in python?

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, group-by

I have the following data frame:

```
Column A    Column B
MD223       GATE IN
MD223       GATE OUT
MD223       LOADED
MD223       DEPARTURE
SC511       GATE IN
SC511       LOADED
SC511       SHIPPED
KR977       DISPATCHED
KR977       LOADED
KR977       SHIPPED
```

What I am trying to do is for each group of the same values in column A to find the first row with the value 'LOADED' in column B and then return rows before the value 'LOADED'. So expected outcome would be:

```
Column A    Column B
MD223       GATE IN
MD223       GATE OUT
MD223       LOADED
SC511       GATE IN
SC511       LOADED
KR977       DISPATCHED
KR977       LOADED
```

I would appreciate your help.

***Update***

The initial data frame has duplicates in column B but the outcome must be the same.

```
Column A    Column B
MD223       GATE IN
MD223       GATE OUT
MD223       LOADED
MD223       DEPARTURE
MD223       LOADED
SC511       GATE IN
SC511       LOADED
SC511       SHIPPED
SC511       LOADED
KR977       DISPATCHED
KR977       LOADED
KR977       SHIPPED
```

Expected outcome:

```
Column A    Column B
MD223       GATE IN
MD223       GATE OUT
MD223       LOADED
SC511       GATE IN
SC511       LOADED
KR977       DISPATCHED
KR977       LOADED
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets do `cummax` per group in Column A to flag the all the rows before the first `LOADED` the use `loc` to select all the flagged rows

```
mask = df['Column B'] == 'LOADED' 
df.loc[mask[::-1].groupby(df['Column A']).cummax()]
```

Update: If you have duplicates in `Column B`

```
mask = df['Column B'].eq('LOADED') & ~df.duplicated(subset=['Column A', 'Column B'])
df.loc[mask[::-1].groupby(df['Column A']).cummax()]
```

Result

```
  Column A    Column B
0    MD223     GATE IN
1    MD223    GATE OUT
2    MD223      LOADED
4    SC511     GATE IN
5    SC511      LOADED
7    KR977  DISPATCHED
8    KR977      LOADED
```

Comment: Thank you! It is working but it turns out I have duplicated rows with 'LOADED' in column B and I cannot drop duplicates. How can I get the same result? I have updated the question. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

Group by `Column A` and slice each group to first valid index denoted by `LOADED` value:

```
df.groupby('Column A', sort=False)\
    .apply(lambda x: x.loc[:x['Column B'].eq('LOADED').idxmax()])\
    .reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
  Column A    Column B
0    MD223     GATE IN
1    MD223    GATE OUT
2    MD223      LOADED
3    SC511     GATE IN
4    SC511      LOADED
5    KR977  DISPATCHED
6    KR977      LOADED
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, which works also in the presence of duplicates:

```
df.loc[(df.groupby('Column A', sort=False)['Column B']
        .transform(lambda g: ~g.shift().eq('LOADED').cummax())),:]
```

Output:

```
   Column A    Column B
0     MD223     GATE IN
1     MD223    GATE OUT
2     MD223      LOADED
5     SC511     GATE IN
6     SC511      LOADED
9     KR977  DISPATCHED
10    KR977      LOADED
```